# I made simple student work automation with pycharm python with buttons. I need to open this project with django, but I can't install django

Tags: python, django, url, pycharm

I have a simple button student work automation project that I made with pycharm python. This is my school homework. I need to make a django connection and open it in django, I couldn't manage it, I did it all over again, I can't manage the url definitions, can anyone help me please

I installed django with my research, made some progress and got this error

'' The install worked successfully! Congratulations!
You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs ''
but now i deleted django, i went back to the beginning, can anyone install django from the beginning please

Comment: `pip install Django`?